# Неправильный вывод результата в алгоритме rsa c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, шифрование, вывод, rsa

Скажу сразу что я далеко не професиональный кодер и знаю что программа написана боком коком перескоком
но все же не могу не попросить помощи

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <cstdlib>
long int p, q;
unsigned long long n, e;
bool flag(0);
long int gcd(int x,int y);
bool checkPrimeNumber(long int n);
long int extnod(unsigned long long a,long int b, unsigned long long* x, unsigned long long* y);
std::string msg{};
unsigned long long rsa_d(long int p, long int q, long int e);
unsigned long fpow(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long m);
int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a prime number of P ";
        std::cin >> p;
            if (checkPrimeNumber(p)) 
            {
                goto loop_e;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "\nWRONG INPUT\n";
            }
    }
    loop_e:
    for (;;)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a prime number of Q ";
        std::cin >> q;
            if (checkPrimeNumber(q)) {
                goto loop_q;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "\nWRONG INPUT\n";
            }
    }
    loop_q:
    n = p * q;
    flag = false;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(;;)
    {
        e = RAND_MAX;
        if (gcd(e, (p - 1) * (q - 1)) == 1 && 1<e<(p-1)*(q-1))
        {
            goto rand_e;
        }
    }
rand_e:
    std::cout << std::endl << e;
    std::cout << std::endl << n;
    long int b{ (p - 1)*(q - 1) };
    unsigned long long x, y;
    unsigned long long* x1{ &x };
    unsigned long long* y1{ &y };
    unsigned long long d;
    d=rsa_d(p,q,e);
    std::cout << std::endl << d;
    std::cout << "\nWrite your message: ";
    std::cin >> msg;
    unsigned long long encoded_message{ 0 };
    for (char c : msg) {
        encoded_message = encoded_message * 128 + c; // ASCII encoding
    }
    unsigned long long encrypted_message{ fpow(encoded_message,e,n) };
    std::cout << "\n" << encrypted_message;
    unsigned long long decrypted_message{ fpow(encrypted_message,d,n) };
    std::string decoded_message;
    while (decrypted_message > 0) {
        decoded_message.insert(decoded_message.begin(), static_cast<char>(decrypted_message % 128)); // ASCII decoding
        decrypted_message /= 128;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << decoded_message;
    return 0;
}

long int gcd(int x, int y)
{
    return y ? gcd(y, x % y) : x;
}

bool checkPrimeNumber(long int n) {

    bool isPrimeNumber = true;



    // 0 и 1 не являются простыми числами 

    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {

        isPrimeNumber = false;

    }

    else {

        for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i) {

            if (n % i == 0) {

                isPrimeNumber = false;

                break;

            }

        }

    }

    return isPrimeNumber;

}

long int extnod(unsigned long long a,long int b, unsigned long long* x, unsigned long long* y) {

    int q, r;
    int x2 = 1, y2 = 0, // x(i-2)=1, y(i-2)=0
        x1 = 0, y1 = 1; // x(i-1)=0, y(i-1)=1

    do {

        // Алгоритм Евклида
        q = a / b;
        r = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = r;

        // Расширенный алгоритм Евклида
        *x = x2 - x1 * q; // x(i) = x(i-2) - x(i-1)*q
        *y = y2 - y1 * q; // y(i) = y(i-2) - y(i-1)*q

        // "Сдвиг истории" назад
        x2 = x1; y2 = y1; // Старый x(i-1), y(i-1) перемещается в x(i-2), y(i-2)
        x1 = *x; y1 = *y; // Новый  x(i), y(i) становится x(i-1), y(i-1)

    } while (r > 0); // Перебирать, пока не станет r = 0

    // И записать разультат, где x = x(i-1), y = y(i-1)
    // т.к. ранее мы "сдвинули" в (x2, y2) старые (x1, y1)
    *x = x2; *y = y2;

    // Вернуть значение НОД
    return a;
}
unsigned long long rsa_d(long int p, long int q, long int e) {
    unsigned long long phi_n = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
    unsigned long long x, y;
    long int d = extnod(e, phi_n, &x, &y);
    if (d != 1) {
        // обработка ошибки
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return x % phi_n;
    }
}
unsigned long fpow(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long m) {

    int id;
    unsigned long r = 1;
    for (id = 31; id >= 0; id--) {
        if (b & (1 << id)) r = (r * a) % m;
        if (id) r = (r * r) % m;
    }
    return r;
}
```

и такая "чудесная" программа выдает такой абсурдный результат
[image]

что делать чтобы исправить подобное?

Answer (score 0):

Самое первое, ещё не доходя до алгоритма rsa  - это первоначальный перевод строки в число.

```
unsigned long long encoded_message{ 0 };
for (char c : msg) {
    encoded_message = encoded_message * 128 + c; // ASCII encoding
}
```

операция `*128` по сути - это сдвиг влево на 7 бит. Фраза `I love you`, которую вы пытаетесь закодировать состоит из 10 символов, т.е. вам понадобится 70 бит на её представление таким способом. А `unsigned long long` - это переменная размером 64 бита. Т.е. вы получите потерю данных. Кроме того - зачем вообще переводить строку в число?  В данном случае вы кодируете 1 символ 7 битами. А массив `char` (std::string) - это 8 бит на 1 символ. Экономия в 1 бит за счет кучи вычислений? Оно того не стоит.

Не ошибка, но глаз режет - использование `goto`. Зачем? Ведь дальше вы в функции `checkPrimeNumber()` прекрасно используете прерывание цикла с помощью `break`.

```
for (;;)
{
    if (checkPrimeNumber(p)) 
        goto loop_e;
// должно быть 
for (;;)
{
    if (checkPrimeNumber(p)) 
        break;
```

При вызове `gcd()` велика вероятность переполнения - как повезет.

```
long int gcd(int x, int y);

gcd( e, (p - 1) * (q - 1))
```

Вот это написание сравнения `1<e<(p-1)*(q-1)` - некорректно. Оно интерпретируется как `( 1<e ) < (p-1)*(q-1)`.

```
if ( && 1<e<(p-1)*(q-1))
// должно быть
if ( && 1 < e && e < (p-1)*(q-1) )
```

Весь этот цикл либо срабатывает сразу, либо становится бесконечным. Т.к. внутри цикла ничего не изменяется. Зачем здесь вообще цикл?

```
for(;;)
    {
        e = RAND_MAX;
        if (gcd(e, (p - 1) * (q - 1)) == 1 && 1<e<(p-1)*(q-1))
        {
            goto rand_e;
        }
    }
```

Дальше смотреть устал.
Разбейте программу на маленькие кусочки. Тестируйте каждый кусочек отдельно.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь!

Comment: цикл сделан для того чтобы если поточное число e не подошло цикл шел дальше и менял значение e пока не нашел удовлетворяющее условию

Comment: Спасибо здесь - принятый ответ. Число е в цикле не изменяется. Никак. Оно всегда равно `e = RAND_MAX` Поэтому никакого "дальше" нету.